# parallelism and thread with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

If I'm trying to make a simple parallelism implementation in javascript:

- 1 main programme, which will create the different thread.
- 1 thread, which will read a `.txt` file, and which will push each word into an array.
- 1 thread, which will read the array and print the first element + delete the first element if the array is not empty.

Last thing I try :

main.js:

```js
const { fork } = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');

const forked = fork('child.js');

const openFile = async (text) => {
    fs.readFile(text, async function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("impossible a lire")
        }
        else{
            console.log("début lecture du fichier")
            data = data.toString().split(" ");
            for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                console.log("mot dans parent = " + data[i])
                forked.send({ mot: data[i] });
            }

        }
    })
}

openFile('input.txt')
```

Child.js:

```js
process.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
```

But this look like to be concurrency and not parallelism.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you are a bit confused by the terms. Parallelism (or parallel execution) is a method of achieving concurrency. Concurrency simply means running multiple tasks independently such that one task is not dependent on the other one. Read more about it here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190719/the-difference-between-concurrent-and-parallel-execution

Comment: You only have one activity here (read file and iterate through the words) so it's not clear what you want it to run in parallel with.

Comment: It's also not clear how you think concurrency and parallelism are different in this context.  What are you expecting the result here to be?

Comment: That's the problem, Javascript seem to not support parallelism, every-time I try new way, this is concurrency. I want to make 2 threads and 1 main process